# Display 2 random pictures PHP with no duplicates

Tags: php

I'm a bit of a noob in PHP and I'm learning it right now. I'm making a website that displays 2 random pictures side by side. However at the moment with my current code, it means on some occasions you may get the same picture loaded twice. Here is my code:

```
<img src="images/
<?php
$pics = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg');
echo $pics[array_rand($pics)];
?> " />

<img src="images/
<?php
$pics = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg');
echo $pics[array_rand($pics)];
?> " />
```

Comment: Is each of the two images always pulled from the same list?  Or could there be differences?

Comment: Hint: `array_rand()` has an optional second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following

```
<?php
$pics = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg');
$images = array_rand($pics, 2);
?>

<img src="images/<?php echo $pics[$images[0]]; ?>" />
<img src="images/<?php echo $pics[$images[1]]; ?>" />
```

Comment: Cheers! worked perfectly. So I guess that the '2' parameter in array_rand means it picks 2 from random. Then when you reference $images[0] and $images[1] it displays those two images it picked yes?

Comment: That's right! The second parameter is to tell how many results you want from randomization.

Answer (score 1):

array_rand can return a list of random entries, instead of just one.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
<img src="images/
<?php
$pics = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg');
$keys= array_rand($pics, 2);
echo $pics[$keys[0]];
?> " />

<img src="images/
<?php
echo $pics[$keys[1]];
?> " />
```

Answer (score 1):

Determine the two random images first, and then handle the display part.

```
<?php
$pics = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg');
$indexes = array_rand($pics, 2);
?>

<img src="images/
<?php
echo $pics[$indexes[0]];
?> " />

<img src="images/
<?php
echo $pics[$indexes[1]];
?> " />
```